# How can we change the color of period (dot) over i/j using css or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

I understand that parts of a character cannot be changed unless the character is changed overall; However, is there a way to change the color of the dots given over i/j using css or JavaScript?

Comment: this might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dotted_and_dotless_I

Answer (score 1):

You can add another character prior to the one you want with css and position it absolutely. Then cut the line off half way (the ".4em" might change depending on the font family).

```
.reddot span.j:before, .reddot span.i:before{
    content:'j';
    position:absolute;
    color:red;
    height:.4em;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.reddot span.i:before{
    content:'i';
}
```

Here's some JavaScript to wrap your text in spans:

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('reddot');

for (var i in items){
    items[i].innerHTML = items[i].innerHTML.replace(/([ij])/g, '<span class="$1">$1</span>');    
}
```

See it in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/653st8kb/